# How do I get git to give me an acceptable pkgver for Atom which I can use to check it out?

Tags: git, pkgbuild

I am working on the atom-editor-git PKGBUILD in the AUR, hoping to turn it into an Atom equivalent to the gvim-git PKGBUILD. See the gvim-git PKGBUILD updates its package version whenever it is run to the latest release of gVim, e.g., if I was to run it right now it would build a package for gVim 7.4.1236. The atom-editor-git PKGBUILD, however, returns the package version `1.4.0.r653.g41029f6` when `1.4.2` is the latest release of Atom. gvim-git uses this `pkgver()` function:

```
pkgver() {
 cd $_pkgname
 git describe --tags | sed 's/^v//;s/-/./g'
}
```

while atom-editor-git uses:

```
pkgver() {
  cd "$srcdir/atom"

  git describe --long --tags | sed 's/\([^-]*-g\)/r\1/;s/-/./g;s/^v//'
}
```

the obvious solution would be to replace `git describe --long --tags | sed 's/\([^-]*-g\)/r\1/;s/-/./g;s/^v//'` with `git describe --tags | sed 's/^v//;s/-/./g'` in the atom-editor-git PKGBUILD, but running `git describe --tags | sed 's/^v//;s/-/./g'` in the [Atom git repository](https://github.com/atom/atom/) gives:

```
1.4.0.653.g41029f6
```

which is not in the format I want (`1.4.2`), so I suspect that what I need to get atom-editor-git to package the latest release of Atom is an alternative git line in the `pkgver()` function and that is what I am here for. To be clear, I want `pkgver()` to give me `1.4.2` exactly for the current version, not `v1.4.2` or `v1.4.2-1-<COMMIT>` where `<COMMIT>` is the 7-character commit short-descriptor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atom uses the `stable` branch for its stable release builds, so to find the latest tag for a release you need to check that branch:

```
$ git describe --tags stable
v1.4.2-1-ge9db64c
```

To retrieve the corresponding tag, keep everything up to the first `-`:

```
$ git describe --tags stable | cut -d- -f1
v1.4.2
```

To get the version without the leading `v`, strip that off:

```
$ git describe --tags stable | cut -d- -f1 | sed 's/^v//'
1.4.2
```